# Phonegap - saving VCard data to contacts on Android and iOS (2019, Phonegap cli-9.0.0, phonegap builder v2)

Tags: contacts, phonegap, vcf-vcard

All other similar questions are now outdated, so I'm posting this question in the hope that someone has a more modern answer.

My phonegap app has a barcode scanner. It returns correctly with whatever text the QR Code returns with. One of the sample barcodes I tested was a VCard, with full VCard text, starting:

```
  BEGIN:VCARD
  VERSION:3.0
  FN;CHARSET=UTF-8:A Test
  ...
```

I want to take this raw text and parse it as a VCard, saving the contact details to my device's contacts list.

Previously this was possible using cordova-plugin-contacts, but this is now not only deprecated (due to security questions) but also causes the app to crash when using various more modern Android OS's.

Is there another way to do this? I tried saving the data as a .vcf file and then tried to open the file but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No perfect answer was found. I decided to parse the raw data and use cordova-plugin-contacts even though it is deprecated. I fixed the crashing issue by ensuring a JIT permissions check for READ_CONTACTS.